# Pandas - ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe

I am trying to do a simple apply function over a data frame as follows:

```
titanic = pd.read_csv("/home/myuser/Downloads/titanic_train.csv")

X_train = titanic.drop(["Survived", "PassengerId"], axis=1)
Y_train = titanic["Survived"]
X_test = titanic_test.drop(["PassengerId"], axis=1)

def calc_dist(row, x):
    return 1.0
for index, test_row in df.iterrows():
    distances = X_train.apply(calc_dist, args=(test_row), axis=1)
```

Here above, I am not yet calculating any distance but just trying to `apply()` function stub. I am testing out the function and for this test, the `distances` will have a series, all `1.0` floats.

But I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-e4ef82dbd06e> in <module>
      2     return 1.0
      3 for index, test_row in df.iterrows():
----> 4     distances = X_train.apply(calc_dist, args=(test_row), axis=1)
.
.
.
.


ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going through `df.iterrows()` try:

```
distances = X_train.apply(lambda f: calc_dist(f['test_row']), axis=1)
```

In this way you'll be creating a new column with the return value of the function `"calc_dist"` using as arg the column `'test_row'` from `X_train` dataframe.

Comment: This kind of worked, but I still used a loop. Not working without loop. What worked for me - `for index, test_row in df.iterrows():
    distances = X_train.apply(lambda f: calc_dist(f, test_row), axis=1)

print(distances)`

Comment: did you manage to calc "distances" with that formula ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
def calc_dist(row, x=None):
    return 1.0

for index, test_row in df.iterrows():
    distances = df.apply(lambda row: calc_dist(row), axis=1)

print(distances)
```

Prints:

```
   1.0
   1.0
   1.0
   ...
```

Comment: Not working. says - `TypeError: calc_dist() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

Comment: calc_dist requires only one 'row' argument. Remove the 'x' argument. See my change as well.

Comment: I don't want to remove `x`. I need it.

Comment: The example you gave doesn't need the X argument. If you just want to keep it anyway, just assign it to none during the function definition. I have updated the solution to be more generic now.

**P.s.** Just so that people know when (not) to downvote a solution. The downvote is applicable when the solution is incorrect or irrelevant. In this case, however, your problem is being solved with a generic solution.